# get file path when downloading with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I want to play music while downloading, so i play music with local file, how can i get file path in tmp directory while downloading with NSURLSession.

The method **URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:** than only call while file downloaded, so what should i do

Comment: Why do you need to know the path before the download ends? Before the download ends, there is no file and no path. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: The music is online, so I want to cache partial data before play it

Comment: Then you can't use a download task.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get file location as it's being downloaded, just don't use download task. For example, create a `NSURLSessionDataTask` and stream it to persistent storage yourself (e.g. create your own `NSOutputStream` for local file in persistent storage and open it, and then in `didReceiveData`, just write the data to your stream, and close the stream when you're all done). Then you can do whatever else you want with the stream/file. If using AFNetworking, I believe that the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` exposes an `outputStream` property for this purpose, too.

Comment: AFNetworking 3 removes `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. If you are using AFNetworking 3, you will have to use the `setDataTaskDidRecieveDataBlock:` method on `AFHTTPSessionManager` in some way to do what @Rob is describing above.

Comment: hey I didn't find method 'didReceiveData' can you please tell me where I will get the method Thanks.

Comment: It's part of [`NSURLSessionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDataDelegate/URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:) protocol. So, create your own `NSURLSession` with [`sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession/sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:) and implement `didReceiveData` in your delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what @matt said, before the download ends you could do nothing except wait.
But you could consider use [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) to play your music while downloading.